# Matplotlib interactive window in server mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

While experimenting with some math and plotting, I constantly change a script and rerun it. The script computes a function and finally shows a plot.

After changing the script and to rerun it, I first have to CTRL-C to stop the script and thereby the display of the plot, but this is terribly slow (two to three two seconds 'hold-your-breath' each time, very annoying). Mousing over to the plot window to close it is even more cumbersome.

Therefore it would be great, if I could fire up the plot window just once, likely in a different process and then let the script contact the plot window to send it the plot commands. Is this mode possible?

(An alternative might be to use matplotlib.ion() in ipython and source the script each time, but for a clean state I would prefer to rerun the script from the command line.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your desire to keep the figure open but interact with it from multiple runs of a different script is pretty hard.  As you say, you might be able to use the ipython option - I can't see many other options as you have to somehow "tell" the figure about using your script as the data source, or "tell" your script about the already running process containing the figure.